# Ubuntu 16.10 MariaDB Cannot Connect Remotely - Where's the config?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb

I need to access my MariaDB installation from another PC on my local network but get the following error:

ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.127' (111)

I know this is because it's bound to localhost but I can't seem to find the relevant config file.  I have tried several but it looks like this:

/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf

is the only one with settings in it but after restarting I still cannot access.  As a test I temporarily changed the port to 3305 from 3306 and running lsof -i -P | grep :3306 still showed mysql running on 3306 so I know the settings are not taking.

Where is the config file or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out what was wrong:

> /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf

Is the correct file but for some reason

> service mysql restart

Didn't take so I tried rebooting and it's fixed!  Hope this helps someone..